# Java Unit testing with time

Tags: java, unit-testing, time, junit

I save records with the a timestamp in an oracle database. 
This timestamp indicates the moment of a several event.

I need the age of the oldest item. In a logical way this means

> current time - time event

I use folowing SQL code to get the age of the oldest item from my database

```
select dm1.name_event,
  TO_CHAR(MAX(TO_DATE('20000101','yyyymmdd')+(SYSDATE - dm1.time_event)),'hh24:mi:ss') as "age_of_oldest_item"
from dm_procmon dm1
```

As good practise I want to test this code in my java application with JUnit.

```
@Test
public void oneItem() throws SQLException {
    stm = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO DM_PROCMON (DM_ID, WORKFLOW, NAME_EVENT, TIME_EVENT) VALUES(DM_ID.nextval,'1-EF.txt', 'up', ?)");
    stm.setTime(1, new Time(getTime(1, 0, 0))); // 1 hour
    stm.execute();

    ResultSet resultSet = connection.createStatement().executeQuery(Utilities.resourceToString("logi.sql"));
    Time currentAge = new Time(0);
    if (resultSet != null) {
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            currentAge = resultSet.getTime(4);
        }
    }

    Assert.assertEquals(new Date().getTime(), currentAge.getTime());
}
```

I get an assertion error. What I think the problem is is that there is a timestamp difference between the statement which gets executed and the time with the assertion statement happens.

The assertion output is

> java.lang.AssertionError: 
>   Expected :1428398404004
>   Actual   :33604000

So I think there is maybe also a rounding mistake in my approach.
What is the solution for this?

Comment: the Time you get from the DB has its date set to 1st Jan 1970...

Comment: Tried but didn't work

Comment: What does this `getTime( xxx )`-method do? As you use it in `new Time(getTime(1, 0, 0))`. That code is missing.

Comment: getTime replaces the new Time(HOUR : int, MIN : int, SEC : int) constructor. This constructor is deprecated, which means it won't be able to be used in the future. So I wrote a help method to still do it in this way.